# Checkbox and form submit don't work well with onChange method Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, methods, onchange

I have an array of string in my script, and I have 2 functions one to filter the string by maximum and minimum length and one method to exclude some strings according to the character they have. These two methods don't work well together, and they don't show the appropriate array when I uncheck them.

Here is my code :

```
<div id="demo"> </div>
<div class="item">
  <form id="aForm" onchange="filter()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="A" value="A">Exclude words with 'A'
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="E" value="E">Exclude words with 'E'
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="O" value="O">Exclude words with 'O'
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="item" id="length">
  <form id="oForm">
    <input type="text" name="minLength" size="2" />Minimum Lenght
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="maxLength" size="2" />Maximum Length
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updateLength()">
  </form>
</div>
```

And here I have my scripts:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var animals = ["Bear", "Mouse", "Cat", "Tiger", "Lion"];

  function filter() {
    var a = document.getElementById('A').checked,
      e = document.getElementById('E').checked,
      o = document.getElementById('O').checked,
      result2; //make a copy

    var copy2 = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var array = copy2.split(" ");

    result2 = array.filter(function(value) {
      value = value.toLowerCase();
      return (!a || value.indexOf('a') == -1) && (!e || value.indexOf('e') == -1) && (!o || value.indexOf('o') == -1);
    })
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result2;
  }
  filter();

  function updateLength() {
    minLength = oForm.elements["minLength"].value;
    maxLength = oForm.elements["maxLength"].value;
    var result = [];
    var copy2 = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var array = copy2.split(" ");
    for (var i in array) {

      if (minLength <= array[i].length && array[i].length <= maxLength) {
        result += " " + array[i];
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }
  }
  updateLength();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have a form in a form?

Comment: `These two methods don't work well together` . . . can you be more specific?  What issues are you seeing?  Are there any errors being thrown in the console?  What are you expecting to see that you aren't?

Comment: When I check to exclude the strings with "E", I get the appropriate strings and then when I filter by values I don't get any string even though there are strings

Answer (score 0):

Put your `updateLength()` function outside of the `filter()` function, and put the `onchange` listener on all of the inputs, not on the form. The status of the form itself isn't changing, the inputs are.

Comment: udateLength and filter are separated